# How to resist anonymous user to access module internal files? eg. path starts from \Drupal\module\mymodule\files

Tags: 8, users, navigation

I have one file placed in my module. I want that only authenticated users or admin can access the content of this file. For anonymous users, it should be shown 'You don't have permission to access...'

Link is like `<a href = "' . $base_url . '/' . drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module') . '/files/myfile.xml" target="_blank">Sample File</a>'`

Right now issue is, even if i logged out, I am able to see the content of this link.

I tried this:

```
if(isset($user->roles[1])) {
        global $base_url;
        return $mylink;
      }
```

but above code is not working for me.

What is the best possible way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I've understood your requirement correctly, you've some files other than normal Drupal files, like csv, txt which should not be accessible to Anonymous user.

This should be done at .htaccess level or you can give a try to private file system in Drupal Core. Check the ans given to "[how to restrict file access to specific user roles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9850031/377342)" for more details on Private File system. The question is related to Drupal 7 because of which contributed modules will not be available for Drupal 8. But you can check configuration options mentioned for Drupal 8 Core.

Comment: No, none of the above approach is working. Still I can access the link from anonymous user. The path(my link) starts from `domain/modules/mymodule/file...` .Can't we put any limit that such paths starting with '/Drupal/modules/` should be unassailable for anonymous users?

Comment: Ohh... So you've some files other than normal Drupal files, like csv, txt which should not be accessible to Anonymous user, correct?

Comment: yes right... I have a folder structure like .. module -- mymodule--file--sample.xml   And I want if someone(anonymous user) directly access this file link, he shouldn't access the content of that xml file.

Comment: Understood. This can't be handled using above method. This should be done at .htaccess level or you can give a try to private file system.

Comment: Check out this [ans](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9850031), The question is related to Drupal 7 because of which modules will not be available for Drupal 8. But you can check configuration options mentioned for Drupal 8 Core.

Comment: ok, thanks, it means at code level we can't restrict these files to get accessed, except .htaccess wat.

Comment: No, because the code was just controlling the link display. But suppose if user already has a link and tries to access that directly, he will be able to access file. I've also update ans as per our latest discussion above.